# ssh key gen Permission Denied

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, ssh-keys

I am trying to make ssh key for a the deployer user

```
[deployer@server /]$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@yahoo.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/deployer/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
open /home/deployer/.ssh/id_rsa failed: Permission denied.
Saving the key failed: /home/deployer/.ssh/id_rsa.
```

i have tried all of theses

```
[root@server /]# chmod -R 644 /home/deployer
[root@server /]# chmod -R 755 home/deployer
[root@server /]# chmod -R 755 /home/deployer
[root@server /]# chmod -R 755 home/deployer
```

Comment: Are you the owner of that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the privileges to save the files necessary to complete the operation.  Try running the same command using `sudo`:

```
sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@yahoo.com"
```

When prompted for a password, enter your password.  If this doesn't work, you can try using the command `su`, which will switch to the `root` user directly.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `deployer` is not the owner of its own home directory. Try giving him the ownership:
`[root@server /]# chown -R deployer: /home/deployer/`

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

1) cd /home/deployer

2) ssh-keygen --t

3) chmod 700 .ssh